# PIL/SciKitLearn/Cluster Image Segmentation and Clustering

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, data-science, k-means, scikit-image

I hope someone can help me. I'm doing a data science project (as a beginner) and I'm using k-means clustering as an image segmentation tool to count the number of fruit on a tree displayed in an image.
I was able to read the image, turn it into a numpy array, and clustered the pixels (I did this by  creating a data matrix of the number of pixels in the image x 3 and then used k-means). I then used model.cluster_centers to get the cluster centers. I then compressed the image with each pixel location being the value of the cluster center.

What I'm struggling with now is how to segment the image into two: an image with just the fruit and an image with everything but the fruit. Did I not create a binary mask already?

I am also tasked with counting the amount of fruit displayed in the image. I've been told I have to use measure.label from skimage but I am not sure where I would even go from my segmentation to that.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. I tried looking up image segmentation examples or documentation but I didn't find anything useful. Also haven't learned OpenCV so I'd rather just focus on sklearn, PIL, np, and matplot.plt. My code is below. Thanks!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from PIL import Image              
from IPython.display import display 

im = Image.open("Fruit.jpg")
display(im)

from numpy import asarray
data = asarray(im)
#print(data.shape)
#Data was (1000, 649, 3)
plt.imshow(data)

k = 8
X = data.reshape((-1, 3))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
kmeans.fit(X)
pred=kmeans.predict(X)

c=kmeans.cluster_centers_.reshape(1,8,3).astype(int)
plt.imshow(c)

X2=np.copy(X)
for x in range(X.shape[0]):
    X2[x]=c[0,pred[x]]
X2=X2.reshape(1000,649,3)
plt.imshow(X2)
```